# .NET stop waiting for a database event which does not arrive

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, events, communication

I'm working on a really big project developed by two teams, one (mainly) for the database, and one (where I am) mainly for the GUI and helper classes as an interface between GUI and DB.
Obviously, there are errors in communication, and - of course - we can't assume 100Mbit bandwidth & super-fast server computer.

Language is C# .NET, target "framework" is WPF **and** Silverlight.

When a user clicks a button, the GUI asks the DB (through helper classes) for information. Let's say... pizza types. The server should answer *"{Funghi,Frutti di mare,Prosciutto}"*. When DB sends his answer, we receive a "database.Ready" event and fill our datagrid.

**BUT** if the user clicks the button while we haven't received the answer yet, the GUI sends an another request to the database. And the whole system tries to serve the user.
But it can't, because when the second request is sent, the first is disposed when we want to read it. So *NullReferenceExceptions* occur.

I've solved this by implementing kind of a semaphore which closes when user input occurs and opens when the Ready event (the functions it calls) finishes working.

**Problem:**
If I don't receive the Ready event, no user input is allowed, but this is wrong.

**Question:**
**Is there a common (or at least, working) solution to stop waiting for the Ready event and...**

1) re-sending the request a few times, hoping we receive our pizza types?

AND/OR

2) Dropping the request, tell the user that database failed to send the answer, and re-open the semaphore?

I can't post code here as this code is the property of a corporation, I'd rather like to have theoretical solutions, which are okay for professionals too.

Sorry for the long post, and **thank you for your answers!**

Comment: Disable button until response is received.

Comment: I've already done this:*I've solved this by implementing kind of a semaphore which closes when user input occurs and opens when the Ready event (the functions it calls) finishes working.

Problem: If I don't receive the Ready event, no user input is allowed, but this is wrong.*

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not clear to me: what is the purpose of the database.Ready event? You send a request, the server send back an answer, and then the database.Ready event?

Comment: When the database sent the data to my helper class, the helper class raises a "Ready" event to notify me.

Comment: `await Task.Delay(someTimeOut);` and then `if (!databaseReady) UI.IsEnabled = true;` and then `CleanUpPreviousCall();`. Seems pretty easy to me.

Comment: I'll try the logic, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are already using a background thread to dispatch the query to the database and wait for it's response. You can use the `Task` API that was introduced in .NET 4.0 to cancel such a request. For that, you pass in a `CancellationToken` that signals the status to the executing task. You can obtain a `CancellationToken` via a `CancellationTokenSource` as shown in the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_CallDatabase(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(CallDatabase, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void Button_OnNavigate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If you navigate, you can cancel the background task and thus
        // it will not execute any further
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    private void CallDatabase()
    {
        // This simulates a DB call
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        // Check if cancellation was requested
        if (_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Request cancelled");
            return;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Update Controls with DB infos.");
    }
}
```

Note that this example is simplified, you can and should use this in another component (e.g. view model).

If you still want to use the Ready event, you could also just unregister from it when you navigate away, so that no further actions will be performed when it is raised.

Comment: Looks nice, I like this too! (assuming I can implement cancellation)

Comment: user @HighCore commented this (I rewrote "and then" to "..."):

`await Task.Delay(someTimeOut);
...
if (!databaseReady) UI.IsEnabled = true;
...
CleanUpPreviousCall();`


His "CleanUpPreviousCall" method could do the cancellation, I think.

Comment: I was thinking over if the two methods are compatible and I think your solution assures that database sends an answer, so if don't, I'm where I started. @HighCore instead is just waiting for the answer. Both answers seems to be less than sufficient, but the seem to be good, combined.

Now I'm rebuilding the project, I'll be back when it finished.

Comment: This works on an empty project (I can't reset it, though) but I put it in the existing project and can't even call the CallDatabase method.


`private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
 
 
 
protected override void OnMagicalPropertyChanged(int newValue)
        {
            base.OnMagicalPropertyChanged(newValue);


            if (this.mIsTemplateApplied)
            {


                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(CallDatabase, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            }

        }`

Comment: I can't exactly see why your code cannot call the `CallDatabase` method - it just has to be an instance method that takes no parameters and has void as the return type. Can you post your whole code?

Comment: I can't copy the code because we have 200+ projects with our own controls (with .NET controls as base class) and other stuff I can't modify, nor show you.

Comment: I currently put a `DispatcherTimer` which re-enables the UI after a few seconds. I feel this is not a good solution, but seems to be a solution :/

Comment: `this.mTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    this.mTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                    this.mTimer.Start();
                    this.mTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mTimer_Tick);`

`void mTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.mTimer.Stop();
            this.mTimer.Tick -= this.mTimer_Tick;
            this.mIsControllableFromOutside = true;
            this.mIsReadyToRead = true;
            this.mTimer = null;`

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? I don't know the context, but you should ask the following questions:
- Is the user allowed to resend a request when currently another request of the same kind is in progress? If yes, then make the code cancellable like shown in the example above.
- If he shouldn't be allowed to do that, then just disable the button and tell him (maybe via a text block right next to the button) that a request is currently in progress. There is no standard pattern how to do this - it depends on the context.

Comment: I still do not understand why you cannot specify a delegate for `CallDatabase` as an argument for the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method - can you specify the compiler error that is generated?

Comment: There is no compiler error. The problem is, when I send the request, I disable the GUI and if the database does not send an answer, the GUI remains disabled.
I'm looking for a widely suitable and accepted solution for this conflict.

I'll accept your answer, because what you posted is okay and is working, but I still don't have the working solution :(

Comment: If you could post some code (it does not need to be your production code but a small sample project that shows your problem), I'm sure that I or someone else will help you. But it's hard with just a description of the problem (e.g. we don't know if your event is static or not, how the helper class that you use to call the database layer is structured etc.).

Comment: Furthermore there are some common patterns like the Repository pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) that can be disposed via `IDisposable` when it is no longer needed, thus freeing all resources like database connections.